# How can I export a java project from eclipse to an ssh terminal and run it without getting "unable to find class" errors?

Tags: java, ssh, compiler-errors, export, mobaxterm

I want export the java files from my eclipse project on my pc into an ssh terminal where I can submit the code so my professor can grade it. I don't really know the proper way to do this. I just copy pasted the java files in the src folder in the eclipse workspace for my project and pasted them into a directory in the terminal. When I try to run javac *.java to compile the code, I get a whole bunch of errors ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPkpD.jpg)). If I remove MaxHeapTest.java (junit class), the code seems to compile okay with javac *.java. However, now when I try to run the driver class. MyLifeInStardew.java, I get a NoClassDefFoundError. Here is an image of that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ixij.jpg

Also note, the only files I'm allowed to submit as per the instructions are the ones shown in the src folder in the image. I cannot package the project as a runnable JAR file. I have to submit it as these loose source files which my professor should be able to run on his machine.

Project Folder on my machine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFzRO.jpg
src folder contents: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9huG2.jpg

I did some googling and it sounds like this has to do with the classpath, which isn't working anymore because I move the files to a new location. I'm really struggling to find an answer to how I can fix this.

Comment: If you have your project working in eclipse, why don't you just submit the source files? Why do you need to compile them again manually? Where does `ssh` come into it? Is eclipse running on a different computer?

Comment: Is there a class discord or slack channel??  This feels like a "how do I submit the code" question that's probably been answered. If nothing else, your professor will probably help.

Comment: @tgdavies : I have eclipse running on my computer, however I have to submit it to a remove server via ssh. So I have to connect to the school server, then import my project source files into some directory on the server, and then submit it from there. I need to compile them manually on the server and test them to make sure they work on the server.

Comment: Your classes are in the package `p2`. They have a line `package p2;` at the start, correct? So the name of the class you want to run is `p2.MyLifeInStardew`, as the error message says. But I think you should talk to your teacher -- do they really want you to recompile and test your code on the machine you submit on?